# Passing parameters to nested routes

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an angular app and I am trying to achieve the following routes:

```
/networks
/network/nameofnetwork
/network/nameofnetwork/shows
/network/nameofnetwork/show/nameofshow
```

my problem is that I can get to all of the routes but the only state param that is being called is the name of network but not the show. Heres my module:

```
angular.module('network',[])
    .config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider){
        $stateProvider
            .state('networks',{
                url: '/networks',
                templateUrl:'/templates/network/networks.tpl.html',
                controller: 'ViewNetworksCtrl'
            })
            .state('network',{
                url: '/network/:username',
                templateUrl:'/templates/network/network.tpl.html',
                controller: 'ViewNetworkCtrl'
            })
            .state('network.schedule',{
                url: '/schedule',
                templateUrl:'/templates/network/schedule.tpl.html',
                controller: 'NetworkScheduleCtrl'
            })
            .state('network.shows',{
                url: '/shows',
                templateUrl:'/templates/network/shows.tpl.html',
                controller: 'NetworkShowsCtrl'
            })
            .state('network.show',{
                url: '/show/:slug',
                templateUrl:'/templates/network/show.tpl.html',
                controller: 'NetworkShowCtrl'
            });
    }])


.controller('ViewNetworksCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){}])
.controller('ViewNetworkCtrl',['$scope','$stateParams',function($scope, $stateParams){
    console.log($stateParams);      
}])
.controller('NetworkScheduleCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){}])
.controller('NetworkShowsCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){}])
.controller('NetworkShowCtrl',['$scope','$stateParams',function($scope, $stateParams){
    console.log($stateParams);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From chatting in the IRC channel I found out that I was missing a nested